# How to combine all the columns' data into single column as an XML document

Tags: php, mysqli, innodb

In a MySQL book I came across a part which was said:

> If you have many long columns in a single table, it might be better to combine the data they store into a single column, perhaps as an XML document. That lets all the values share external storage, rather than using their own pages.

I actually have 6 TEXT columns as below:

```
question TEXT NOT NULL,  
option1  TEXT NOT NULL,  
option2  TEXT NOT NULL,  
option3  TEXT NOT NULL,  
option4  TEXT NOT NULL,  
answer   TEXT NOT NULL
```

and I want to prevent this from happening (every column has its own pages) in InnoDB tables. How should I implement this?
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new Column
2. Run a script to enter the data of the 6 Columns into an XML(see below) and fill the new column with it.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <newColumnName>
     <question>
        <![CDATA[Insert value of column question here]]>
     </question>
     <option1>
        <![CDATA[Insert value of column option1 here]]>
     </option1>
     <option2>
        <![CDATA[Insert value of column option2 here]]>
     </option2>
     <option3>
        <![CDATA[Insert value of column option3 here]]>
     </option3>
     <option4>
        <![CDATA[Insert value of column option4 here]]>
     </option4>
     <answer>
        <![CDATA[Insert value of column answer here]]>
     </answer>
   </newColumnName>
   ```
3. Change every Databaserequest and parse your XML to get the data

Comment: So XML's content and its tag should be inside a variable, then I should store its content in the appropriate column in a table. correct me if I'm wrong. tnx.

Comment: If you talk about your script to save your data. Yes :)